# Get SharePoint Hub Site associated Sites CSOM

Tags: rest, sharepoint, csom

How do we get or retrieve the associated sites in a SharePoint hub site using CSOM or REST API? I don't find API methods for this. Please suggest me a solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the REST API below to get information about all hub sites that the current user can access.

```
/_api/HubSites
```

Refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/features/hub-site/rest-hubsites-method

More information:
[Hub site REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/features/hub-site/hub-site-rest-api)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the link. But the method HubSites returns only the hub sites not the associated sites in a hub.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't see a REST API to get the associated sites in a hub in the official document.

Answer (score 0):

Mikael Svenson has a blog post - you can use the SharePoint Search REST API, querying on the managed property called DepartmentId.

More information available here: https://www.techmikael.com/2018/04/working-with-hub-sites-and-search-api.html

An example of a REST call that returns all sites that are joined to a specific hub site (NOT including the hub site itself):

https://`<hostname>`/_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass%3dsts_site AND NOT siteid:`<hubsite-id>` AND departmentid%3d{`<hubsite-id>`}'&refinementfilters='departmentid:string("{*"%2clinguistics%3doff)'&trimduplicates=false

And an example of the same REST call but this time including the hub site itself:

https://`<hostname>`/_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass%3dsts_site AND departmentid%3d{`<hubsite-id>`}'&refinementfilters='departmentid:string("{*"%2clinguistics%3doff)'&trimduplicates=false

`<hostname>` = host to your sharepoint web app, like contoso.sharepoint.com

`<hubsite-id>` = id (GUID) of the hub site

Comment: Please include the essence of your solution in your actual answer, as it otherwise might become useless if the linked website changes or goes offline.